# Why can't I switch to a virtual avfs directory with quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, home

I installed [avfs](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) to be able to transparent mount archive files as directories.  I created a mount point with:

```
mkdir ~/.avfs
avfsd ~/.avfs
```

From there, I can do things like `cd ~/.avfs/some/path/foo.tar.gz#/` fine.

However, I've noticed that if I enclose the path in double quotes, `cd` fails:

```
~ $ cd ~/.avfs/usr/local/bin/
~/.avfs/usr/local/bin $ cd "~/.avfs/usr/local/bin/"
bash: cd: ~/.avfs/usr/local/bin/: No such file or directory
```

Why would quotes matter?  I wouldn't expect the quotes to be visible to anything but the shell, but this seems to happen only with paths involving `~/.avfs`.  The only explanation that I can think of is that `bash` is validating the path (which, because it's virtual, doesn't exist yet), but I can't explain why quoting would cause that.

I am using `bash` 4.3.48(1)-release. `avfsd` reports for version information:

```
FUSE library version: 2.9.4
fusermount version: 2.9.4
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.19
```

Comment: That reminds me: [I have a bit of automation around cd to switch into ~/.avfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366178/automate-cd-into-an-archive-directory-under-avfs/366179#366179)

Comment: @Gilles Nice!  The reason why I encountered this was because I was writing a function to automatically `cd` into `~/.avfs`, but your version is much nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that when you enclose the path in double quotes, the ~ does not get expanded by your bash - normally programs have no notion that ~ stands for your home directory!

You can validate this by trying the following two commands in bash:

```
# echo ~/test
/home/rabban/test
# echo "~/test"
~/test
```

Comment: Duh.  I even tested not using a `~` by doing `cd "/home/jamesdlin/.avfs/"` and remember getting a failure, but I must have made a typo at the time.  I should have known...